# Spring Cloud AWS SQSListener Interceptor for Converter

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-aws

Please take into consideration that the following example is from a SNS Topic with a SQS subscription, not a simple sqs message.

I'm currently using an SQSListener which receives a message from an SNS Topic with success:

```kotlin
@SqsListener("\${my-test-queue}")
fun featurePlacingListener(@NotificationMessage myJob: MyJob, @Headers headers: MessageHeaders) {
    
  // Some code here

}
```

I would like to have an interceptor somehow so when there's a deserilization error I can log and send a notification.
I know this can be done If I forget using the **@NotificationMessage**, grab the Message part and deserialize manually but I would like to keep this clean.

Spring AOP doesn't work because the converter does the job before.

Something similar to a Controller advice or a nice AOP interceptor would be great

```
org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not read JSON: Cannot construct instance of `com.example.MyJob`, problem: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method com.example.MyJob.<init>, parameter myProperty
at org.springframework.messaging.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter.convertFromInternal
```

I just want to be able to detect when this happens.

Comment: Did you find the answer to this?

Comment: Nope, end up building an extension to deal with the deserialization and throw a custom exception so I can then send a notification.